# select statements for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, ios, css

Normally on a mobile device, when you use a select statement, the option values popup on the bottom of the screen instead of below the popup itself.

I don’t want to navigate with this popup, but rather select a value that will be saved.

```
<select size="1" name="points" >
<option value="">Select Points</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I’ve tried jquery and normal HTML, and I can’t find a way to do this on a mobile device.

I have tried this on Safari for iPhone, Chrome for iPhone. No joy.

I thought about an unordered list, but I don't know how to capture a value from an unordered list in a form.

Can anyone help me out here? Or is this just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674492/3526510
In jQuery, you can detect the clicks on the li's for example